# Is it Possible to Find out The Relative Magnitude of Different Modes in MultiDOF Second Order Differential Equations Without Knowing the Detail Initial Condition

Tags: differential-equations

Given that I have a matrix of second order differential equations [of this form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibration):
[image]

Where `M`, `x`, `C`, `K` are matrix and vectors.

I can decomposed the solutions into different eigenvalues and eigenvectors, as dictacted by the theory of eigenvalue problem, and then solve the equations for each mode of eigenvectors, provided that I have the initial condition for the `x` and the first derivative of `x`.

My question is, if the initial conditions are unknown, is there anyway I can still tell the relative magnitude for different eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your equations form a linear inhomogeneous system of ODEs, so any linear combination of the eigenvectors (of the homogeneous problem) could be added to any "particular solution" to yield a solution for some other choice of initial conditions.  Thus you could only get a condition on relative magnitudes if you had some restrictions on your initial conditions.